# I am trying to building a telegram bot with integrated chatGPT to review my coding errors

Tags: python, telegram, openai-api

This is the code

````
import os

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify 

from telegram import Update, Bot

from telegram.ext import MessageHandler, filters, Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackContext
from queue import Queue

import openai

# Replace with your OpenAI API key
openai.api_key = "openAI_API_KEY_HERE" 

# Replace with your Telegram Bot API token
TELEGRAM_API_TOKEN = "bot_Token_here"

bot = Bot(token=TELEGRAM_API_TOKEN)

update_queue = Queue()
updater = Updater(bot=bot, update_queue=update_queue)

dispatcher = Dispatcher(updater.bot, update_queue)
dispatcher.use_context = True


# Define a function to handle incoming Telegram messages
def handle_message(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
  message_text = update.message.text
  chat_id = update.message.chat_id

  # Check if the message is code-related and needs assistance 
  if message_text.startswith("/codefix"):
    # Extract the code from the message 
    code_to_fix = message_text[8:] # Adjust the index as needed

    # Send the code to ChatGPT for assistance
    response = openai.Completion.create(
      engine="davinci", # Use the appropriate ChatGPT engine  
      prompt=f"Fix the following code:\n```{code_to_fix}```",
      max_tokens=50 # Adjust the response length as needed
    )

    # Extract the response from ChatGPT
    fixed_code = response.choices[0].text
    
    # Send the fixed code back to the user
    bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=f"Here's the fixed code:\n```{fixed_code}```")

  else:
    # Handle other non-code related messages here
    bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text="I can only assist with code fixes. Use /codefix to get help.")

# Define a command handler  
def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
  update.message.reply_text("Welcome to the CodeFix Bot! Send /codefix followed by your code for assistance.")

# Set up the message handler
message_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, handle_message)
dispatcher.add_handler(message_handler)

# Set up the command handler
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  # Start the Telegram bot updater and the Flask app
  updater.start_polling()  
  app.run(debug=True)
````

this is the error im getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Student\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\CHATGPTSERVER.py", line 23, in <module>
    dispatcher = Dispatcher(updater.bot, update_queue)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'Dispatcher' is not defined
```

I have asked chatGPT how to fix this but the telegram module has updated and im not yet advanced enough to learn what needs doing from reading the documentation. If any one could help me figure out why im getting this error thank you.

I have tried changing the D in dispatcher to lowercase that broke it even more, I have tried asking chatGPT but it keeps giving me the same line of code that already exists for the fix ANY information on this is helpful.

Comment: Have you defined `Dispatcher`? No, hence the error. [ask]

Comment: The error is straightforward. There is no definition for something named `Dispatcher` anywhere in your program.  It is not the name of a class, function, or other variable you have defined yourself, nor is it something you imported.  Simply put, it does not exist, just as the error says.  What were you **expecting** it to be?

Comment: You need to import `Dispatcher` from library `telegram-ext`. Your line 4 becomes like this `from telegram.ext import MessageHandler, Filters, Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackContext, Dispatcher  # Add the Dispatcher import
`

Comment: Ok i have added the Dispatcher in the imports ( i dont know when it got removed sorry about that part ) this is the error i am getting now and this is the one that has me baffled 

'''Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Student\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\CHATGPTSERVER.py", line 23, in <module>
    dispatcher = Dispatcher(updater.bot, update_queue)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'Dispatcher' is not defined
'''

Comment: Sounds like you **didn't** add Dispatcher in the imports.  Or maybe you did, but then you forgot to save the code?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes that is correct i have updated my issue if you could help me figure out what i need to do in order to fix this it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @HeinzSiahaan already said exactly how to fix this.  So **do that**.  What is so hard about this?

Comment: @JohnGordon well you cant import the dispatcher from telegram.ext i had to create the dispatcher because of this and the new error above is the most recent issue i have also update the topic to have the updated code and updated error. If importing the dispatcher would have fixed my errors i would have closed the thread.
``` 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Student\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\CHATGPTSERVER.py", line 22, in <module>
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Updater' object has no attribute 'dispatcher'
```

Comment: Also when you try to import the Dispatcher this is the error you will receive 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Student\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder\CHATGPTSERVER.py", line 7, in <module>
    from telegram.ext import MessageHandler, filters, Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackContext, Dispatcher
ImportError: cannot import name 'Dispatcher' from 'telegram.ext' (C:\Users\Student\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\__init__.py)

Comment: Which telegram.ext's version did you use @Macs? In v.1.3.3, it's there. This is the documentation [https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v13.3/telegram.ext.dispatcher.html](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v13.3/telegram.ext.dispatcher.html). Maybe you want to downgrade you version or searching for current version implementation code.

Comment: I am using version 20.05 ill downgrade the version and try and see if this fixes it @HeinzSiahaan

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `Dispatcher` from library `telegram-ext`.

Your line 4 will become like this:

```
telegram.ext import MessageHandler, Filters, Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackContext, Dispatcher  # Add the Dispatcher import
```

If you can't find the `Dispatcher` object, maybe you need to downgrade version of your `telegram-ext` to match your code to `v13.3`. Here is the documentation about dispatcher https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v13.3/telegram.ext.dispatcher.html.

Comment: Instead of sticking to an old version (which BTW is `13.3`, not `1.3.3`), the code should be updated to work with the latest version. If they got rid of `Dispatcher` for some reason, there's gotta be an alternative to that in the current version.

Comment: Thank you for correction. Updated. Yes, that's the best action. But, maybe asker have some constraints. Need more info about that.